# PostgreSQL simple SELECT query didn't work with WHERE (newbie)

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I try to start work with Pgadmin4, and when i use query like this:

```
select *
from users
```

I get normal results like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utHrN.png)

and when i use query like this:

```
select *
from users
where login='admin'
```

i get nothing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibayc.png)

i've tried to use 'like' and no changes
i've tried to use 'admin' w\o quotes and no changes
what's my problem here?

Comment: From your picture (pictures are not good SO practice btw), I think your login column might contain 'admin' (including the quotes). Try: `select * from users where login ilike '%admin%' limit 10;` Always put a limit at the end of your query

Comment: `where login = '''admin'''`

Comment: Your problem would seem to be your values are being saved quoted as in `'admin'` instead of `admin`.